# Avoid two of the same componets alter each other Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I have a component for Tabs, it has its own variables and it works really good, but the thing is that if i place again other tab in the same page, when i change the value of the selected tab for one, it changes the other tab component also.

This is my tab component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sys-tab',
  styleUrls: ['./shared/sys.css'],
  template: `
    <div class="tabs">
      <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index" (click)="selectTab(tab)">
        <input id="tab-{{i+1}}" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-{{i+1}}" [checked]="i===0"/>
        <label for="tab-{{i+1}}" class="tab-label-{{i+1}}">{{tab.title}}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class TabView {
  tabs: TabViewContent[] = [];
  addTab(tab: TabViewContent) {
    if (this.tabs.length === 0)
      tab.active = true;
    this.tabs.push(tab);
  }

  selectTab(tab) {
    this.tabs.forEach((tab) => {
      tab.active = false;
    });
    tab.active = true;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sys-tab-content',
  styleUrls: ['./shared/sys.css'],
  template: `    
      <div class="content-2" [hidden]="!active">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
   `
})
export class TabViewContent {

  active: boolean;

  @Input() title: string;

  constructor(tabs: TabView) {
    tabs.addTab(this);
  }

}
```

It works really fine if i use it this way:

```
<sys-tab>
  <sys-tab-content title="Principal">
   Content 1
  </sys-tab-content>
  <sys-tab-content title="Complementar">
   Content 2
  </sys-tab-content>
</sys-tab>
```

but if i do something like this:

```
<sys-tab>
      <sys-tab-content title="Principal">
         Content 1
      </sys-tab-content>
     <sys-tab-content title="Complementar">
           Content 2
       </sys-tab-content>
    </sys-tab>
<sys-tab>
      <sys-tab-content title="Principal">
         Content 3
      </sys-tab-content>
     <sys-tab-content title="Complementar">
           Content 4
       </sys-tab-content>
    </sys-tab>
```

When i change the value of the first component, it also change the value of the second and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify different name for each of `input[radio]` group:

```
name="{{id}}-radio-set"
```

and unique `id` and `for` attribute for all controls.

So here is how it could be done:

```
let nextId = 0;

@Component({
  selector: 'sys-tab',
  template: `
      ...
        <input id="{{id}}-tab-{{i+1}}" ... name="{{id}}-radio-set" .../>
        <label for="{{id}}-tab-{{i+1}}" ...></label>
      ...
  `,
})
export class TabView {
  id = `tabview-${nextId++}`;
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/crHnFltb2D5b4vlWqvb7?p=preview)**

Comment: That was the perfect solution... Thanks a lot